# Python tkinter: Handle multiple tabs

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Ok, I have this simple code:

```
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('test')

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

f1 = Text(root)
f2 = Text(root)
f3 = Text(root)

nb.add(f1, text='page1')
nb.add(f2, text='page2')
nb.add(f3, text='page3')

root.mainloop()
```

and I am just wondering, what is the best way to handle multiple tabs with text on them in tkinter? Like if I wanted to erase all the text on just 'page2' or insert something on 'page3' how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the references to the text widgets in `f1`, `f2` and `f3`, so you can call their methods directly:

```
f2.delete(1.0, 'end') # erase all the text on the 2nd tab

f3.insert('end', 'hello, world') # insert text on the 3rd tab
```

You might also want to add the widgets to a list, in case you want to perform the same action for all.

```
texts = [f1, f2, f3]
for text in texts:
    text.delete(1.0, 'end')
```